# daily limit of Reviewing first post

Tags: support, review, rate-limiting

I've reviewed 20 first post then system shows "Thank you for reviewing 20 First Posts today; come back in 7 hours to continue reviewing." Why there is a daily limit in it?

Comment: As with all other things, SE believes in not allowing unbounded behavior. See e.g. [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447).